# How to attach fuel line to bottom of car

Tags: honda, accord, fuel-line

I have a 2001 Honda Accord LX and I'm changing the fuel lines. I will use mounting brackets, but I have some questions about the screws I should use.  What type of screw, how long, and what size pilot hole? Is there anywhere on the underside of the car I should NOT drill into? Here are the brackets.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered self-tapping screws?

Comment: What became of the original fuel line supports?

Comment: @Paulster2 I've seen some self tapping screws, but there are many kinds.  Do you have any recommendations?  Also, can I attatch them pretty much anywhere on the undercarrage or are there certain areas to avoid?

Comment: @jwh20 The original supports, at least most of them, were part of a plastic grill covering the brake, fuel, and evap lines.  The grill traps moisture and salt, so I don't want to put it back on.